# How do I determine the type of a Python type annotation at runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection, python-typing

I want to inspect the type annotation of a class variable, and if it is a `typing.Literal`, extract the literal value and do something with it. But:

```
from typing import Literal
class Foo:
    bar: Literal['baz']

l = Foo.__annotations__['bar']
isinstance(l, Literal)
```

yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/tbabb/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/python3.8/typing.py", line 342, in __instancecheck__
    raise TypeError(f"{self} cannot be used with isinstance()")
TypeError: typing.Literal cannot be used with isinstance()
```

Also, `l.__class__ == Literal` is `False`, so that doesn't work either.

Why doesn't the `isinstance()` check succeed? How do I check the type of annotation that's being used?

Comment: For one reason, your Foo class has not implemented an __annotations__ method.

Comment: @itprorh66: I don't see anything wrong with the Foo class, the question is about making use of annotation objects. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: __annotations__ is a dict that provides some annotations about global(?) variables, classes, class attributes, function parameters and return types. __annotations__ is one of the names that is present in the top level scope ( __name__ == '__main__'   You are calling foo.__annotations__ which implies a method within the Foo class.  Since Foo class doesn't contain a __annotations__ method,, it isn't working.  What happens if you call __annotations__ directly

Comment: see [Annotations Best Practices]https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html() for explanation on how to address your issue.

Comment: @itprorh66, did you run the code above? The `__annotations__` dictionary is filled automatically the moment you add annotations to any members of the class, it is not required that the user implement it manually. And the syntax above uses a (correct) dictionary index, not a function call.

Comment: According to [Annotations Best Practice](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/annotations.html) Python 3.10 adds a new function to the standard library: inspect.get_annotations().. For 3.9 accessing the annotations dict of an object is much more complicated because of a design flaw in these older versions.  See the article for best approach.

Comment: @itprorh66, that isn't relevant to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typing_inspect` library solves this by [checking](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect/blob/master/typing_inspect.py#L225) the annotation object's `__origin__` attribute. This should evaluate to `True` if the annotation for `bar` is a Literal:

```
a = Foo.__annotations__['bar']
isinstance(a, Literal[''].__class__) and a.__origin__ is typing.Literal
```

Note that `isinstance()` by itself is not enough, because other type annotations use the same class:

```
class Z:
    x: Literal['plumbus']
    y: List[int]

axns = Z.__annotations__
axns['x'].__class__ is axns['y'].__class__
> True
```

This is why the check of `__origin__` is also necessary.